# iText7: How to fix: One PdfTextFormField with two combs, SetValue No MaxLen Error

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I have a PDF file with acroforms that I am trying to fill out using iText7. I am getting an error when there are two Comb fields with the same FieldName when I try to use field.SetValue("1234"). Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
    iText.Kernel.PdfException: 'No /MaxLen has been set even though the Comb flag has been set.'
```

Calling textField.GetMaxLen() shows the comb length set in Acrobat (10). Calling textField.SetMaxLen(10) before calling SetValue has no effect. Nor does SetMaxLen(10) with a RegenerateField() call after. Inspecting the pdfObject, I see the following:
    `{<</DA /Helv 12 Tf 0 g /FT /Tx /Ff 29360128 /Kids [28 0 R 29 0 R ] /MaxLen 10 /T CombTestField >>}`
So I see the /MaxLen 10 entry, but I still get the error above.
The two widgets are Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V copies of each other. Both are combs of 10 chars.

```cs
var pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inFile), new PdfWriter(outFile));
var form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, false);

var field = form.GetField("CombTestField");

if (field is PdfTextFormField textField)
{
    var maxLen = textField.GetMaxLen();
    if (maxLen == 10)
    {
        textField.SetValue("1234");
    }
}
```

So I am getting the error with 2 comb widgets. I delete one of them and the problem goes away. I am working with a client's form, so cannot simply remove the second widget. Any fix or even workaround would be welcome.

EDIT: Here's the file in question. http://www.filedropper.com/combtest
EDIT2: iText  7.7.1.5

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: @mkl I found the bug on a more complicated PDF, but this small one I generated (and attached) also shows the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known bug and it has just recently been fixed. A snapshot version including the fix is already available (7.1.6-SNAPSHOT). Although alternative workarounds should exist, I wouldn't recommend to consider them as a solution, because some other issues with forms processing have also been improved since 7.1.5. So please try out the snapshot :)

Comment: Is there a C# snapshot available?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can download it here: https://repo.itextsupport.com/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/nuget/itext7/itext7.7.1.6-SNAPSHOT.nupkg